# The "most likely" value of a random variable S with a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ is $S = \langle np \rangle$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory, binomial-distribution

I am working through Example 11.1.3 on p. 353 of [the Second Edition of Thomas & Cover's "Information Theory"](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~cgong821/Wiley.Interscience.Elements.of.Information.Theory.Jul.2006.eBook-DDU.pdf):

> We show that $\frac{1}{n+1} 2^{nH(k/n)} \le \binom{n}{k} \le 2^{nH(k/n)}$.

I am following the proof of the upper bound fine, but I do not understand the initial claim used to prove the lower bound. It says:

> For the lower bound, let $S$ be a random variable with a binomial distribution with parameters n and p. The most likely value of $S$ is $S = \langle np \rangle$. This can easily be verified from the fact that
>   $\frac{P(S = i+1)}{P(S = i)} = \frac{n-i}{i+1} \frac{p}{1-p}$
>   and considering the cases when $i < np$ and when $i > np$. Then, since there are $n + 1$ terms in the binomial sum,
>   $1= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k(1−p)^{n−k} \le (n+1) \max_k \binom{n}{k}p^k(1−p)^{n−k} = (n+1)\binom{n}{\langle np \rangle} p^{\langle np \rangle} (1-p)^{n - \langle np \rangle}$

Probability is not my strong suit and I am not sure what it means by the "most likely" value of $S$ is $S = \langle np \rangle$. I Googled "mode of binomial distribution" and found that [the mode is $\lfloor (n+1)p\rfloor$  or $\lceil(n+1)p\rceil - 1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Is $\langle np \rangle$ common notation for this or am I misunderstanding what is being said? This notation is not explained in the "list of symbols" in the back of the textbook either.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote the most likely value of $S$ as $i_m$.

If $i_m$ is the most likely point then the two conditions apply

\begin{align}
P(S = i_m) \geq P(S = i_m - 1) \\
P(S = i_m) \geq P(S = i_m + 1)
\end{align}

which implies

\begin{align}
\frac{P(S = i_m)}{P(S = i_m - 1)} &\geq 1\\
 \frac{n - (i_m - 1)}{(i_m - 1) + 1} \cdot \frac{p}{1 - p} &\geq 1 \\
 \implies i_m \leq np + p
\end{align}

and also

\begin{align}
\frac{P(S = i_m + 1)}{P(S = i_m)} &\leq 1 \\
\frac{n - i_m}{i_m + 1} \cdot \frac{p}{1 - p} &\leq 1 \\
\implies  np - (1 - p) &\leq i_m  
\end{align}

combining the two results gives $ np - (1 - p) \leq i_m \leq np + p$.

$(1 - p)$ and $p$ are both numbers in $(0,1)$ so as $n$ tends to $\infty$, $i_m$ tends to $np$.